# ElasticSearch - How to search by type?

Tags: elasticsearch, caching, elasticsearch-6

I've put an item into ElasticSearch with given index and type. How do I retrieve it?

Details:

The [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-type-query.html#query-dsl-type-query) states this:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "type" : {
            "value" : "_doc"
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't get it. What do I do with that?

I tried to run it like this but it didn't work:

```
curl XGET 'http://localhost:9200/disney/_search' -d '
{
    "query": {
        "type" : {
            "value" : "disneytype"
        }
    }
}'
```

This throws an error:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
'http://localhost:9200/disney/_search'.
At line:1 char:1
+ curl XGET 'http://localhost:9200/disney/_search' -d '
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Any ideas how to run it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you've got is not related to Elasticsearch. It is some issue with PowerShell. Replace `cURL` call with `Invoke-WebRequest`:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Method 'POST' -Uri 'http://localhost:9200/_search' -ContentType "application/json" -Body '
{
  "query": {
    "type": {
      "value": "disneytype"
    }
  }
}'
```

I personally prefer to use [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana) for discovering my ES indices. It is much more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to run it inline like this:

```
curl.exe -XGET --data-binary '{ "query": { "type" : { "value" : "disneytype" }, studioid: "AAAAA" } }' -H 'content-type: application/json;' http://localhost:9200/
```